# incremental quantile regression

Tags: regression, quantile-regression, online-algorithms

I am reading about quantile regression. I wonder if there is a way to incorporate new data into the regression model and update the parameters on the fly. [1] seems to propose a similar idea, however, it looks like there are some assumptions that need to hold before obtaining the solutions via simplex algorithm such as initial dataset having at least as many elements with associated `(r^+ - r^-)` values equal to zero as the the dimensionality of the input space. So, if there is no such guarantee, is this approach not feasible?

[1] Møller, Jan Kloppenborg, Henrik Aalborg Nielsen, and Henrik Madsen. “Time-adaptive quantile regression.” Computational Statistics and Data Analysis 52.3 (2008) : 1292-1303